# Querydsl with predicate multiple conditions on parent and child table

Tags: querydsl, predicate, multiple-conditions

I'm using springboot with java 8, querydsl 4.2.1

I've a structure from database where, a person table containing name, address, active_status. A person can have multiple kyc documents with their validity. KYC documents are in kyc_document table.

I need to get the active persons, where their kyc documents are valid on today's date.

Below is my code.

```
    QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;
    QKycDOcument qKycDOcument = QKycDOcument.kycDOcument;
    Predicate datePredicate = JPAExpressions
                    .selectOne()
                    .from(qKycDOcument)
                    .where(qKycDOcument.fromDate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())),
                            qKycDOcument.toDate.isNull().or(qKycDOcument.toDate.after(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    )
                    .exists();
    builder.and(qPerson.activeStatus.eq("Active").and(datePredicate));
```

It gives me below query -

```
select
        person0_.RECORD_ID as RECORD_I1_7_,
        person0_.ACTIVE_STATUS as ACTIVE_S2_7_,
        person0_.DECEASED as DECEASED3_7_,
        person0_.GENDER as GENDER4_7_,
        person0_.PROFILE_NOTES as PROFILE_5_7_,
        person0_.RECORD_TYPE as RECORD_T6_7_ 
    from
        PERSON person0_ 
    where
        person0_.ACTIVE_STATUS=? 
        and (
            exists (
                select
                    1 
                from
                    KYC_DOCUMENT kycdoc1_ 
                where
                    kycdoc1_.FROM_DATE<? 
                    and (
                        kycdoc1_.TO_DATE is null 
                        or kycdoc1_.TO_DATE>?
                    )
            )
        ) 
    order by
        person0_.RECORD_ID desc
```

my expected query is :

```
select
        person0_.RECORD_ID as RECORD_I1_7_,
        person0_.ACTIVE_STATUS as ACTIVE_S2_7_,
        person0_.DECEASED as DECEASED3_7_,
        person0_.GENDER as GENDER4_7_,
        person0_.PROFILE_NOTES as PROFILE_5_7_,
        person0_.RECORD_TYPE as RECORD_T6_7_ 
    from
        PERSON person0_ 
    where
        person0_.ACTIVE_STATUS=? 
        and (
            exists (
                select
                    1 
                from
                    KYC_DOCUMENT kycdoc1_ 
                where
                    person0_.RECORD_ID = kycdoc1_.RECORD_ID
                    and kycdoc1_.FROM_DATE<? 
                    and (
                        kycdoc1_.TO_DATE is null 
                        or kycdoc1_.TO_DATE>?
                    )
            )
        ) 
    order by
        person0_.RECORD_ID desc
```

**person0_.RECORD_ID = kycdoc1_.RECORD_ID** is the additional condition in the inner query, which is the requirement and not achieved.

Please suggest, what should be in my predicate builder.

Thanks for the suggestions coming in...

Comment: hi, did you solve your  problem ? ('caus I am having the same issue)